# Multiplying vector element by every other one

Tags: java, vector

Let's assume I have a vector

```
Vec[5] = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}
```

How can I make a method that multiplies:

```
a1*a2, a1*a3, a1*a4, a1*a5
a2*a3, a2*a4, a2*a5
a3*a4, a3*a5
a4*a5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Copy the same vector to another vector and keep that in loop to multiply with each element.

Comment: Is your list right?  It contains `a2*a2` but not contains `a1*a1`.

Comment: Use a nested loop and have the inside loop variable start from the outer loop variable's value.

Comment: What is the return value of the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.length - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < vec.length; j++)
        // do something with i*j
        System.out.print(i*j + " ");
```